# How to create a set of data with differing rows and and columns in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

maybe someone can help me. I calculated different results in R and I am now trying to merge these in one txt. data. However, somehow I am unable to create one datafile where I can have an overview of everything.

One dataframe called "min.temp" with 13 rows and 3 columns (id, dates and values)

```
id Date      Temperature

1. 1967-04-25 -3.086980
2. 1969-04-20 -4.489397
3. 1972-04-26 -5.587154 
4. 1976-04-29 -5.684246 
5. 1976-04-30 -5.297752 
6. 1977-04-20 -3.615099 
7. 1981-04-21 -3.672259 
8. 1981-04-24 -3.860317 
9. 1991-04-20 -4.021680 
10. 1991-04-21 -6.366689 
11. 1991-04-22 -4.785906 
12. 1997-04-21 -4.989829 
13. 1997-04-22 -4.447067
```

and 2 other values "aver.temp" and "max.temp" with only 1 row each and 2 columns:

```
Average temperature: 10 

Maximum temperature: 25
```

I was trying to merge all the information in a list, but it somehow destroys my list when i try integrating all of them. My goal is to get a txt.file called temperature.txt where I can have seperate rows for aver.temp and max.temp and then followd by the rest. In the end, it should look like this.

```
Average temperature: 10

Maximum temperature: 25

id. Date      Temperature

1. 1967-04-25 -3.086980
2. 1969-04-20 -4.489397  
3. 1972-04-26 -5.587154
4. 1976-04-29 -5.684246 
5. 1976-04-30 -5.297752 
6. 1977-04-20 -3.615099 
7. 1981-04-21 -3.672259 
8. 1981-04-24 -3.860317 
9. 1991-04-20 -4.021680 
10. 1991-04-21 -6.366689 
11. 1991-04-22 -4.785906 
12. 1997-04-21 -4.989829 
13. 1997-04-22 -4.447067
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: Not a question mark to be found in this question. :(

Comment: `?cat`, `?write.table`.  You'll want to use `append=TRUE`.  See also `?capture.output` and `?sink`

Answer (score 4):

Most functions for writing to files (`cat`, `write`, `write.table`, etc.) can also write to a file connection, which is the better approach for writing multiple things to a file. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
fh <- file("output.txt", "w")   # creates a file connection

cat("Average temperature: 10", "\n", file = fh)
cat("Maximum temperature: 25", "\n", file = fh)
write.table(min.temp, file = fh)

close(fh)   # closes the file connection
```

Another approach would be to use the `append` option most of these functions also offer:

```
cat("Average temperature: 10", "\n", file = "output.txt", append = TRUE)
cat("Maximum temperature: 25", "\n", file = "output.txt", append = TRUE)
write.table(min.temp,  file = "output.txt", append = TRUE)
```

but this second approach is not as efficient as the first one as the file is opened and closed every time you want to add something to it.

Comment: `sink` is for redirecting the screen output to a file. Because R output comes mostly from `print` statements which the user has little control over, I feel `sink` might be more appropriate for things like session logs, while my solution is preferable for creating reports or exporting data in a specific format.

Comment: ...`capture.output` which is a wrapper around `sink`. Really it's not the nicest and most flexible approach but if it's good enough for you then great.

Answer (score 0):

`data.frame`s can be elements of a list.

```
FinalTextFile <- list()
FinalTextFile$DataFrame <- DF
FinalTextFile$AverageTemperature <- mean(DF$Temperature)
FinalTextFile$MaximumTemperature <- max(DF$Temperature)
```

Comment: Right. It's a list. I'm assuming he can figure out what to do from there.

Comment: The OP knows how to make a list and asks for help getting that list into a text file.  So, this answer is not very helpful.

Comment: "I was trying to merge all the information in a list, but it somehow destroys my list when i try integrating all of them." I took that to mean that he was having trouble getting all the information into the list, either by cbinding the data frame with the max temp or something along those lines.